# SoundPool issue - bad performance on a specific device/API level

Tags: android, media-player, lag, soundpool

OK, this one is a  bit odd.

My app is an OpenGL ES 2.0 game and uses MediaPlayer to play the background music (not on a service as I want the music to stop when the app is send into the background) and SoundPool to play the (various, short) sound effects.

It's been tested on aprox 18 devices and a wide range of OS versions with no problems.  However I recently ran it on a Hudl2 tablet with Lollipop installed and the performance was pretty bad (very choppy).

If I use my games settings to turn off the sound, it runs fine (strangely, if I leave the sound on and turn off the music, it also runs fine).

However, there are a lot of questions here relating to SoundPool causing lag, so I'm going with SoundPool being the likely cause.

Things I've tried are:

- Playing a muted sound in my gameloop
- Using MP3's instead of .OGG's
- Reducing the number of simultaneous streams
- Playing the sounds from the UI Thread (normally I call 'play' from the GL Thread)
- Checking for API Level and using [SoundPool.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.Builder.html) when it detects API 21+ and the older constructor method when it finds an API of <21
- Turning off USB Debugging and disconnecting from my dev computer
- Removing my AdViews (in case they were causing the problem - clutching at straws here)
- Disabling Hardware Acceleration in my manifest (more clutching at straws)

Unfortunately, nothing that I've listed makes any difference.

After much research, I found some people saying that soundPool should be run on a new thread, however, I already tried it on the UI thread and it made no difference at all.

The only other thing I can think of is that this is some kind of compatibility issues between the Hudl2 and Lollipop.

Does anyone have any other ideas as to what may be causing this lag on one specific device, with this specific OS Version (Lollipop)), or has anyone come across anything remotely similar?  And if so are there any more suggestions?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that I ran it on the same device (Hudl 2) with KitKat installed and it was perfectly fine.  And on my Nexus 10 with Lollipop again, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Any update?
I'm in the exact same situation (OpenGL ES 2.0, SoundPool + MediaPlayer = lag), but since Marshmallow.

Comment: No @Jyaif unfortunately, this one is still an issue for me on Hudl-2 tablets running Lollipop - sounds like it must be a bug that appeared in Marshmallow then if you're experiencing the problem in Marshmallow :-(

Comment: Just out of interest @Jyaif, is the device on which you're experiencing problems also a Hudl2?

Comment: I don't know about the Hudl2, but users have reported the problem on Nexus 6p Marshmallow (!!!), and I've been able to reproduce on Nexus 7 Marshmallow.

FWIW, I can reproduce the issue by playing background music (e.g. using Google Play Music), and playing sound effects with SoundPool in my app.